# iPhone - How can I add the NSStepper control to Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have searched for over 4 hours on the net, but every answer I view seems to assume that the user knows how to add controls to Interface Builder.

How does one add extra controls to IB? (Please assume that I know nothing - which is not too far from the mark!)

From my research to date, it seems that extra controls have to be programmed, but I cannot believe that we all have to re-invent the wheel! Surely it's possible to download a set of controls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder comes with a wide variety of controls that are accessible from the Library window (Tools ▸ Library, or ⇧⌘L) under the Objects tab. If you type NSStepper in the search field at the bottom, it should filter out only the stepper controls. (You're correct, you shouldn't have to re-invent the wheel for basic controls.)

However, while "NSStepper" produces 2 results when editing a Mac NIB/XIB file in Interface builder, when the open IB document is for iPhone, I get *no* search results for "NSStepper", even for "step". It's possible that NSStepper (or an equivalent stepper for Cocoa Touch) doesn't exist for iPhone. I'm not an iPhone programmer, but my guess is that a logical alternative would be a [UISlider](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/) or [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/). (These are links to Apple's docs. Google either class name for find suitable tutorials — I know [howtomakeiphoneapps.com](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/) has some examples.)

Answer (score 0):

Just happened upon this old question... there is now a stepper control for iOS 5.